# What's the best or easiest way to attach a loop tag onto canvas?

Tags: tents, repairs, canvas

What's the best or easiest way to attach a loop tag onto a canvas tent?

A loop tag is a loop of canvas so that I can tie a guy string to the loop tag and then down to a stake so that I can implement the solution to this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17337/how-can-i-prevent-this-canvas-swag-from-sagging-in-the-middle).

Should I sew it on? Glue it on? What type of glue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I was going to do this, I would use a [Speedy Stitcher](http://www.speedystitcher.com/#the-basics) or similar tool,
[image]

to stitch the loop to the tent  and then cover the stitches with a canvas seam sealer.

I wouldn't trust glue as there is going to be a lot of pull on the loop tag (the whole point of adding the loop tag is to be able to exert pull on the tent) but stitches should hold it in place.

The canvas seam sealer would be to prevent leaks.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using the speedy stitcher over needle and thread?

Comment: @Fae A needle and thread won't go through canvas as easily if at all