# Reattaching Tent Rain Fly Hooks

Tags: mountaineering, tents

I have a Mountain Hardwear Trango 3.1 (a four-season tent) that lost the hooks on its rain fly. They simply became unglued from the inside of the fly a little while back. For those not familiar with this particular tent, the inside of the rain fly has about a dozen plastic hooks that it uses to attach to the poles of the tent to hold it on in all sorts of bad weather. The hooks themselves are connected to a bit of fabric which is in turn connected to the fly. In this case, the hooks are still connected to their fabric pieces, but the fabric became disconnected from the fly.

I'm not sure what happened, though my suspicion is that I let the tent get too hot and the glue lost its hold. This happened a few years ago and fortunately I was able to find and collect all of the pieces that fell off.

Now I want to reattach them for an upcoming trip (in about a month, so I have plenty of time) and then re-waterproof the fly as the waterproofing is coming off as well (presumably for the same reason that the hooks came off, though it probably doesn't matter). Waterproofing is easy enough, but I'm not sure the best way to reattach the hooks. According to the MH website, the fly is made of "70D Nylon Taffeta 1500mm PU/SIL". Any thoughts on the best way to firmly reattach the hooks, or, more accurately, the fabric that the hooks are connected to, to such a material?

Comment: have you considered hand stitching?

Comment: No. I supposed I could, but they were originally glued so I figured that was the way to go.

Comment: Would this do it https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/17353/8794

Comment: You have to contact the maker of that tent.  If the fabric is disintegrating what kind of confidence could you have in your tent?  Was the fly and tent stored together?  What is the condition of your main tent?  A fly on a tent is critical.  It has to have air between it and the main tent to be effective.  I'd get a new tent, I am serious.  If that tent is a great tent the company will be the best for advice,

Comment: Thanks, but I never said the fabric of the tent is disintegrating. The glue came undone, that's it. The tent fabric is still in fine shape, though needs to be waterproofed, which is normal tent maintenance anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue with my Trango 2. I contacted Mountain Hardware. They suggested using Seam Grip.

Comment: Welcome Tbaby! This has been here for a year without an answer, so we very much appreciate your contribution!  Have you used that Seam Grip? How did it work out for you? Can you give any advice about the best way to use it? You can add any additional information to your answer by using [edit]. We have a lot of questions about tents and other outdoor activities you may find interesting. We value all questions and answers! Have fun!

Comment: I’ve got the same issue. Very disappointing but wondering how the seam grip worked out for you?